# What will be the response of navigator.platform in KaiOS browser?

Tags: javascript, kaios

I am developing a web application and in a scenario, wanted to know that what will be the response of `navigator.platform` in the KaiOS browser?

Comment: why not just `console.log` it and see?

Comment: Show your code with attempts, please.

Comment: I checked on KaiOS device and found that `navigator.platform` is not working on that its showing blank string. so to detect the OS I am using `navigator.userAgent`. it has the string `KAIOS`.

Answer (score 1):

`navigator.platform` returns an empty string on KaiOS. For device detection, you can check `navigator.userAgent` which should always contain `KAIOS/` followed by the OS version, i.e. `2.5.2`. For example: `Mozilla/5.0 (Mobile; Nokia_8110:48.0) Gecko/48.0 Firefox/48.0 KAIOS/2.5.2`